# How to do something similar to getView() method in Android but using Cursor

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I am quite new to Android.

I have referred the samples provided in Android SDK but they don't provide an example wherein I can use a `Cursor` along with `getView()`.

I read somewhere that `getView()` can't work with Cursor. If this is true, what is the alternative to use a method which works similar to `getView()` but using `Cursor`.

My actual scenario is:

I am getting a `Cursor` which contains data retrieved from the sqlite db. I want to display following inside each listview row:

- An icon in the left of the row
- A text label to the right of this icon
- An icon to the right of this text label

Moreover, I'd have to show/hide the rightmost icon based on certain condition at runtime.

Can somebody point me to the right direction. Possibly some sample code or a link to an online tutorial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a ListView with a cursor, you might check out CursorAdapter instead of ListAdapter.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html